# Reference column by column index

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

have a dataset like an iris, any help will be appreciated,

```
iris %>% head %>% mutate(sum = .[[1]] + .[[2]]) #works

iris %>% head %>% mutate(max = max(.[1], .[2])) #doesnt work
```

Expected answer, find the `max(1st column, 2nd column)`

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species max
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 4.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 4.7
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 4.6
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 5.0
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 5.4
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need elementwise max and this can be achieved with `pmax`

```
iris %>%
    head %>%
    mutate(max= pmax(.[[1]] , .[[2]]) )
```

The issue with `max` is that its usage is

> max(..., na.rm = FALSE)

Here, the `...` signifies

> numeric or character arguments

So, it is taking the `max` value of all the columns passed into the function, rather than the elementwise max of the columns

The `+` is a different function and it is always elementwise, but if we do `sum` (which would be a corresponding candidate to check with `max`), it also does the same behavior as `max`